# Green bars appearing on lower half of screen (AMD)

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

Recently, I've been experiencing a strange visual glitch on my monitor: every few seconds, a thin green bar (or two very close to each other) appears in a random position on the lower half of the screen. On occasion, they stop appearing (mostly when I'm not using the computer.)

I'm using the AMDGPU-PRO driver as far as I can tell. I haven't been able to test the monitor against other operating systems to confirm that it is indeed an Ubuntu issue, but I have yet to see similar errors in BIOS.

Is there any fix for the issue?

Using an AMD RX460 card.

Comment: *I'm using the AMDGPU-PRO driver as far as I can tell.* No, you aren't unless you explicitly installed it. Depending on your hardware you are using either `radeon` or `amdgpu`. Please edit and post the exact AMD card.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: funny, I did actually explicitly install it (from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx)). The **hardware** in use is an RX460, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I suggested an edit to the question itself as comments can disappear for a number of reasons. That said, the question is: **How did it work with the default open-source driver**?

Comment: @CelticWarrior: As in, out of the box fresh install? Barely. Resolution was messed up and it wouldn't let me fix it. The last time I wasn't using the proprietary was almost a year ago though, and on a clean Ubuntu install to boot.

Comment: Unfortunately  I  have nothing else to suggest. The current situation is as explained before: `amdgpu-pro` is still experimental and there are no other proprietary drivers.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: thanks, I guess. Maybe it'll just up and vanish? I'll take a look at the open-source drivers for now.